# merge two integer variables in a single float in python

Tags: python, merge, integer

Is there any way on python to have two integers and merge them in a single float?

for example i have two variable var1=2 and var2=4 and i want to create a new variable var3=2.4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it through string:

```
>>> var1=2
>>> var2=4
>>> var3=float(str(var1)+"."+str(var2))
>>> var3
2.3999999999999999
```

Comment: +1. If you're using this in a script, might be wise to surround it by a `try` `except ValueError`, just in case.

Comment: @TejasPendse, what kind of exception should be raised? I don't understand what could go wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Efficient method that works for any a and b:

```
from math import floor, log10

def combine(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return a
    return a + b * 10**-(floor(log10(b))+1)
```

---

Testing timing for this method and fredtantini's version:

```
from timeit import Timer
from random import randint
from math import floor, log10

def random_pair_generator(n):
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        yield (randint(1, 1000000000), randint(1, 1000000000))
        i += 1

def maths_combine(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return float(a)
    return a + b * 10**-(floor(log10(b))+1)

def string_combine(a, b):
    return float(str(a) + '.' + str(b))

def time(n):
    maths_time, string_time = 0, 0
    for a, b in random_pair_generator(n):
        maths_time += Timer(lambda: maths_combine(a, b)).timeit()
        string_time += Timer(lambda: string_combine(a, b)).timeit()
    print('Maths time:', maths_time)
    print('String time:', string_time)


>>> time(20)
Maths time: 31.402130099450005
String time: 49.468994391525484
```

As expected, using maths is much faster.

Comment: Good, fails for `b = 0` though.